# Add range to each option in a dropdown menu array instead of single value?

Tags: arrays, drupal, range

EDIT:

My original post is included at the bottom of the issue, but was very vague, so I'm trying to update it to make myself more clear. There is a section of my site where users submit reviews of businesses. In one such field, they select whether or not they had a bar tab. They are given the options of None, Drinks, Food, and Both. When they submit their option it is stored in the database as a float value, with None being stored as 0, Drinks as 1, Food as 2, and Both as 3. I then avg all of these values into a single field to display on the pages of the businesses. So, if the a business has an average value of .5 for bar tab it shows up as "None", a value of 1.2 as "Drinks", etc.

I then have a view which displays teasers of all business pages, and the users can filter the results by the results of fields on the business page. I would like to have a dropdown menu to display the options for the filter, but I'm not sure how to assign a range to each value in the array instead of a single value. Here's what I currently have:

```
$options = array(
    '' => 'Any',
    '0' => 'None',
    '1' => 'Drinks',
    '2' => 'Food',
    '3' => 'Both',
    );
```

As you can see, if a user selects "Drinks" as the option in the filter, only pages with a value of 1 in the float field will show up. However, as far as the user is concerned, their selection of "Drinks" should filter all pages with a "Drinks" value, or a float value of  `>.75 && <=1.5`. I need the options in the array to reflect that. So, although the following code is not correct, I'd want something to the effect of:

```
$options = array(
    '' => 'Any',
    '>=0 && <=0.75' => 'None',
    '>0.75 && <=1.5' => 'Drinks',
    '>1.5 && <=2.25' => 'Food',
    '>2.25 && <=3' => 'Both',
    );
```

Does anybody know how to go about doing this? I hope this is clearer than my original post.

ORIGINAL:

I asked this over in the drupal forum a while ago, but I haven't been able to get any responses, so I'm hoping that somebody here can help me out. I have the following code in a module for a select array.

```
$options = array(
    '' => 'Any',
    '0' => 'None',
    '1' => 'Drinks',
    '2' => 'Food',
    '3' => 'Both',
    );
```

However, the problem is that each option is only related to a single value. Is there a way to instead assign a range to each option? The result would be that any value between 0 and 1 is assigned to None, any value between 1 and 2 is assigned to Drinks, etc.?

Comment: Is this a Drupal-specific question? Can you provide more context? I'm not sure what you mean by "select array"...

Comment: Sorry, typed this up rather quickly. The entire code is being used to replace a text box with a drop down select list. The fields being filtered by this are saved as decimals, but displayed as text. This portion of the code is being used to populate the dropdown with its options, so that users can filter their results using the words that they see and not the decimal values stored in the database. Does that help clarify?

Comment: In other words, this part of the code is being used to populate a dropdown menu/select list, which is why I called it a select array (probably incorrectly).

Comment: So this array is specifying the valid options, and there is another array somewhere with float values, and you need to use this array to correlate an array of float values with these strings ("none", "Drinks", etc.)? You can edit your original post, btw... please add a representation of the "input" data (these float values you mentioned), and describe what you want as a result, in code if possible.

Comment: I've edited my issue to hopefully clarify the whole situation.

Comment: Okay, that's *much better*, but there's just one part missing for those of us who aren't specifically Drupal devs... how are the keys of that array used? Are they placed in the value="" attribute of form inputs? Are they passed to a database? And then, more importantly, do you have access to write code after the form is submitted? If so, can you just interpret the integers on that side?

Comment: This is where my somewhat limited knowledge of coding in general gets in my way, but I do believe that they are passed within the value="" attribute. Since the so-called "view" displays all the pages based on database values, I would assume that these form values are indeed passed to the database. I hadn't thought of interpreting the integers after the form is submitted, but I think that I should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our conversation above, and if it's true that the array keys get encoded as the value="" of the form fields, and therefore passed to the subsequent page, the my suggestion is this:

Move your implementation for this to the handling request instead of this form-generating one. I'm not familiar with Drupal development (not in the last 2 years anyway), but I imagine you have hooks on the subsequent request where you can modify the submitted values before they are picked up by the framework for the select query.

Something to keep your eye on: You probably won't be able to simply use strings like this on the other side, since Drupal very likely escapes the values, puts them in quotes, and uses the = comparison operator. You may need to check the Drupal docs for how to specify an expression when selecting.

Comment: If I can alter the form after it's submitted, I'm assuming that I could do it in a similar way to how I have another form altered. The other form is altered in part by this line, to replace a comma with nothing: `$form_state['values'] = str_ireplace(",", '', $form_state['values'])`. If I were to take this approach, do you have any suggestion on how to modify it to apply to this situation? Do you know if I could place a range of some sort within str_replace?

Comment: I'm not sure how Drupal uses that exactly, but the major concern I would have is that to specify a range, you need to provide the comparison operator and 2 comparisons (i.e. `avg > 0.5 AND avg < 1.5`), or else a full expression (`avg BETWEEN 0.5 AND 1.5`). I'm not sure without digging into their documentation (*hint*) on how I would do that. It's possible you will have to expand the array and provide comparison operators (so every value in the submitted array will become 2 values in the array you give to the framework, one for less-than and one for greater-than).

Comment: Yeah I figured after your answer that I'd have to look into the documentation. I just really hadn't realized that this was such a Drupal-specific question. I figured that it was just my code non-knowledge getting the best of me. Thanks a bunch for putting up with my nonsense. If I could give you two answer checkmarks for this question instead of one, they'd be yours.